# Problem whit TikZ 3D graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

I want to draw a 3D graph in tikz; something like z=x/y, this is the code that I've written:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
    title = {Campo in funzione della forza e della carica},
    xtick = {-12,-9,...,12},
    ytick = {-9,-6,...,12},
    xlabel = $\vec{F}$, ylabel = $q$,
    ticklabel style = {font = \scriptsize},
    grid
  ]
  \addplot3 [surf, domain=-12:12, samples=50] 
    { x/y };
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is that where the graph shouldn't exist anyway it exists, I tried to solve the problem, maybe using asymptote instead of tikz but I still can't draw it.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  For someone to help you effectively, it's necessary to know what document class if being used, as well as relevant packages.  Please extend your code to a small compilable example.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit hard to understand what you mean by the description, but possibly you mean that the graph is shown also in regions where `y=0`, and the function is not defined. Since the samples are set to an even number, none of the plot points is evaluated at `y=0`, so this does not happen. You can still cut off the plot by using some restriction, e.g. `restrict z to domain=-5:5`. (If you have an older version, replace `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` e.g. by `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
    title = {Campo in funzione della forza e della carica},
    xtick = {-12,-9,...,12},
    ytick = {-9,-6,...,12},
    xlabel = $\vec{F}$, ylabel = $q$,
    ticklabel style = {font = \scriptsize},
    grid
  ]
  \addplot3 [surf, domain=-12:12, samples=50,restrict z to domain=-5:5] 
    { x/y };
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you this solve my problem